# Rear Axle Damaged

Tags: alignment, axle, rear

I have a 2011 Chevrolet Beat (both Petrol/LPG version).  It has a long history of uneven wear and tear in the rear tyre which neither the tyre companies are ready to accept nor Chevrolet.  I am trying to forget that long history over it.

Recently I took it to a testing centre for a complete testing.  I was told that the rear wheel track was not correct.  I took the car to a mechanic and he adviced me that the arm should have been damaged.  After inspection he says the axle itself is damaged and I should change the whole rear assembly so that i can have a permanent solution.  Do I go with it or do I have any alternatives?  What would be the cost implication if I proceed.  Thanks!

Regards,
Rajiv

Comment: possibly find a junkyard donor, although if it is a common problem it would be hard to tell if the donor was ok.

Comment: Has it has this issue since the car was new? If so, you've taken it into the dealership to get it remedied? If so, they would have record of you taking it in under warranty. If all of this is true, take it back to Chevrolet and press them to fix the issue under warranty, now that you know exactly what the issue is. The reason I say this is because it sounds like a factory defect the way you describe it. Even if the warranty has expired on paper, it doesn't mean Chevrolet shouldn't honor the fact they sold a POS out the door. If they say "no", you're no worse off than you were before.

Comment: I have to +1 Paulster2 on this. As for the "cost," we don't give any particular advice on this because of how much the market varies based on localities. But regardless of where you live, the cheapest solution (where possible) is getting the manufacturer to repair or replace whatever is defective.